# Problem connecting to database via SSH with MySQL Workbench

Tags: ssh, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am having trouble connecting to an external database via SSH with Workbench.  The error that I get says:

```
Could not acquire management access for administration
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'chan' referenced before assignment
```

I assume that the problem was originated after a bad upgrade from a previous version (now I have 6.2 on Ubuntu 14.10), and somehow the new settings weren't refreshed.  However, I don't know which specific settings they are, or how could they be refreshed.

The strange thing is that I CAN connect to the database through the command line, and also to another local database.

Please let me know if you need more details to help me figure out how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a fix.  According to this https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75075 the workaround is to downgrade the python-paramiko package; but Ubuntu 14.10 does not appear to have an earlier version to downgrade to.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.  I had given up on this and ran from terminal whenever I needed the SSH database.

Comment: See Solution here, it worked for me!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070957/database-ssh-connection-cannot-be-established-from-workbench